# Show/Hide all with show/hide sections inside angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-bootstrap

I need to have an overall Show/Hide click to show or hide all the detail divs of a list of "panels" of data.  Also within each panel, there is a Show/Hide click to individually show or hide that div of data.

I think that if the overall show/hide is clicked that the individual click values should be set equal to overall value when clicked.  That way if the individual ones are changed, they are all set to show or hide when the main one is clicked.

This is how I tried to do that:

```
    <div>- <a href='#' ng-click="hideAllDetails = ! hideAllDetails; hideDetails = hideAllDetails">Hide All Details / + Show All</a></div>

    <div class="tender-list" ng-repeat="row in tenders" ng-include="'tender/tender_panel.html'"></div>
```

Where the hide/show part of tender_panel.html is here:

```
     <div>- <a href='#' ng-click="hideDetails = ! hideDetails">Hide Details</a></div>
     <div class="tender-details" ng-hide="hideDetails">

      <table width="100%" id="tender-bottom-table">
        <tbody>
           ...
        </tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
```

There is another table above the tender-bottom-table.  Plus a another table after.

What is happening is that it works fine when initially loaded.  The Hide All/Show All works.  Then I click on the individual show/hides and they work.  But then the All Show/All Hide no longer works and I don't see how clicking the individual links breaks things.

This app is Symfony2 with Angular and Bootstrap.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

one thing you could try is to have a property flag in each tenders item that sets if it's shown/hidden and show the individual item based on if hideAllDetails + their flag is true:

```
<div>- <a href='#' ng-click="hideAllDetails = ! hideAllDetails;">Hide All 
Details / + Show All</a></div>
<div class="tender-list" ng-repeat="row in tenders" ng-
include="'tender/tender_panel.html'"></div>
```

tender_panel.html:

```
<div>- <a href='#' ng-click="row.hideDetails = ! row.hideDetails">Hide 
    Details</a></div>
 <div class="tender-details" ng-hide="hideDetails || hideAllDetails">

  <table width="100%" id="tender-bottom-table">
    <tbody>
       ...
    </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.  Or-ing won't work because as soon as one is true, the other one changing won't matter.  What needs to happen is when the hideAllDetails changes, then all individual sections change to the new selection.  After that they follow the individual clicks, until the All click is clicked again.  The state of the All click needs to be saved somehow.